# Dynamic jQuery Progress Bar - Click Events Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbhhf5xs/6/) where *I'd like to be able to change how "filled" the progress bar is depending on the button clicked*. When I click said buttons, nothing is happening.

I (previously) added in alerts/logs to make sure that I had the click functionality correct and due to those alerts/logs working once a button was clicked, I'm lead to believe that I just have something wrong in the way I am trying to move the progress  bar.

```
$('.quarter').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prev().children('span').css('width','25%');
  });
$('.half').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prev().children('span').css('width','50%');
  });
$('.three-quarters').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prev().children('span').css('width','75%');
  });
$('.full').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prev().children('span').css('width','100%');
  });
```

Comment: If you set the css, you should be able to see that in the DOM when you inspect the element. Do you see that? Also, have you checked if each step in the whole chain of methods returns the expected objects?

Comment: For instance, `$(this)` refers to the element. It's parent is the undefined container element of the fiddle. Then you use `prev()` which gets the element before that container, but obviously your progress bar is not in that element (if it exists at all).

Comment: If you use, for instance, `$('.progress-bar').children('span').css('width','25%');` it works fine. So the problem is just in the fiddle and the relations between the elements in it. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbhhf5xs/8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` is probably not returning what you think it is. Consider that `$(this)` relates to the container that the code itself is in; ponder on that for a while and make a comment if you  need me to elaborate.

**David784** has a great solution for your code as is. Alternatively, consider giving the span that is the *moving* part of your progress bar some identifier. As an example, while the following will work for changing your progress bar to 100%,

```
$('span').css('width', '100%');
```

you'll be changing *every* span in your code if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  $(this).parent().prev().children('span')
```

to

```
$('.progress-bar > span')
```

With jquery, using these `.parent().prev().etc` chains will never end well. It's too easy to break by making small changes to your DOM.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbhhf5xs/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your paragraph holding the links was closed, but not opened:

```
    <p> <!-- Here -->
        <a href="#" class="quarter">25%</a>
        <a href="#" class="half">50%</a>
        <a href="#" class="three-quarters">75%</a>
        <a href="#" class="full">100%</a>
    </p>
```

Fixed JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j6jxpLwx/

Comment: @GolezTrol What is it then? It does solve the problem.

Comment: My bad. It's okay.

Comment: @8protons You're right, I'm actually confused by the new JS Fiddle interface, I was better used to the old one, where all the settings where on the left.